# Pointer having issue to struct in C programming

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am having a problem with pointers.
this is an example of what I want

```
struct Book
{
 char name[10];
 int price;
}

int main()
{

 struct Book b[10];     //Array of structure variables
 struct Book* p;        //Pointer of Structure type
 p = &b;   --- HERE is the ERROR  
}
```

This is the error part

```
p = &b;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have not checked but this should work.
`p = b;`

now if you want to iterate you array of structure then do this

```
// Example program
#include <stdio.h>

struct Book
{
     char name[10];
     int price;
};

int main()
{
     struct Book b[10];     //Array of structure variables
     struct Book* p;        //Pointer of Structure type
     p = b;  

     int i = 0;
     for(i = 0 ; i<10; i++)
     {
         printf("Price : %d\n", (p+i)->price);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

`b` is an array, which can itself decay into a pointer variable. By writing `&b`, you actually take the address of that pointer and then you end up with pointer to a pointer. It is enough to just write `p = b`.

Comment: I did put  p=b  but i am not able to  printf("%i",p[0]->price);   or    printf("%i",p[0].price);

Comment: What do you mean you are not able to print it? printf("%i",b[0].price) should be working just fine.

Comment: This is incorrect. `&b` is a pointer to the whole array, whereas `b` decays to a pointer to the first element. In both cases, you get the same address. No pointer to pointer.

Answer (score -2):

b itself is a pointer. Here you can think of arrays as of pointers. So use `p=b` instead of `p=&b`

Comment: I  put  p=b  but i am not able to  printf("%i",p[0]->price);   or    printf("%i",p[0].price);

Comment: Downvoted, because [arrays are **not** pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c).

Comment: OK, you probably  won't agree with that, but I think that in context of this question, OP made mistake because he did not think about arrays as pointers. So based on that, in this context, I believe it is OK to let him think of arrays as pointers.

Comment: It's not appropriate to spread false information in any context. Arrays are already a special case in C type system, and arrays-are-pointers will only cause more confusion down the line. Understanding when arrays *decay* to pointer is vital when using arrays.

Comment: Yet sometimes, you make simplifications for beginners, in order to increase the speed of their learning. But fair enough, I change my wording.